Nextjs 14 fetch GET request response get cached until the next build
I have this ProductsList component in my next.js project
const loadProducts = ()=>{
const response = await fetch("my-api-end-point", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-store", // Prevent caching
        },
      });
}

 useEffect(() => {
    loadProducts();
  }, []);

This is very simple code where I call a function to load products when component mounted.
I have an admin panel where I enter all of these products. In my local development environment when I do a page refresh newly added products successfully load to the component via the API call.
But in production environmnet these products not loading until I release a new production build. But in production env, when I inspect the network call, I see it calling the correct endpoint but response seems cached. I don't see latest products in that response.
It seems like somehow the endpoint response got cached during the build process. I've added cache-control:no store header but the results is the same.
How can I fix this with next.js 14?

Did you check the production domain in Incognito Mode of the browser? @margherita pizza

Yes. Still the results is same.

@margherita pizza my-api-end-point is this api route handler in NextJS or external API endpoint ?

Please have a try with getServerSideProps if you are using pages router? @margherita pizza
Here, docs mentions that getServerSideProps gives fresh data if you don't need caching.
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops

Got the same error and the problem like you said is due to caching.
This solution worked for me.
Solution :
import this line in your loadProducts component and in your api route file
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' 

Suggestion :

You can upgrade to Nextjs 15 as the caching is turned off by default which makes a lot more sense and will save you a lot of headaches because in Nextjs you will frequently encounter caching errors.

Nextjs caching documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching

Problem :

It seems like somehow the endpoint response got cached during the build process

Possible Cause :

By default, Next.js will cache as much as possible to improve performance and reduce cost. This means routes are statically rendered and data requests are cached unless you opt out. [1]

Solution :

Route Segment Config option [2] [3], will force dynamic rendering
of your page, which will result in routes being rendered for each
user at request time.

The Route Segment options allows you to configure the behavior of a Page, Layout, or Route Handler.

Add this line in the top of the page (1st line of page.js), where
you have imported ProductsList component.

Also if your my-api-end-point is an API Route Handler, add this
line there as well.
This will prevent your page & Route Handler from becoming
static/cached during build time.


You can use any one line from below, both will force dynamic rendering.
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' 

OR
export const revalidate = 0


revalidate [4] option with value zero 0, will also force dynamic rendering.


Read More:

Route Segment Config : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config
dynamic : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic
Caching : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#overview
revalidate : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#revalidate

